# Determine the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-cos(\frac{1}{n}))(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble determining the convergence of the series:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-cos(\frac{1}{n}))(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$

I used $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$ and then tried the comparison test for $0 \le (1-cos(\frac{1}{n}))(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) \le (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ but I can't conclude anything even If I know $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}})$ diverges.
I thought about trying the limit test but I couldn't find a sequence to conclude the convergency.
I also know $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1-cos(\frac{1}{n})$ converges as $1−cos(\frac{1}{n})$ behaves like $\frac{C}{n^2}$ for large values of n

Any guidance, tip or resolution would be highly aprecciated, thank you.

Comment: Multiply by the conjugate of the second piece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

$$1-\cos(\frac{1}{n}) \sim_{+\infty} \frac{1}{2n^2} $$
and
\begin{align}
 \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} &= \sqrt{n} (\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} -1) \\
&\sim_{+\infty}  \sqrt{n} \times \frac{1}{2n} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\\
\end{align}
Thus
$$ (1-\cos(\frac{1}{n}))(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) \sim_{+\infty} \frac{1}{4 n^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

Comment: Sorry If It's too obvious but how did you get the $\sqrt{n} × \frac{1}{2n}$ part?

Comment: I used the taylor expansion $\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} + o(x)(x \to 0)$

Comment: So basically to sum up $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-cos(\frac{1}{n}))(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ $\sim$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4n^\frac{5}{2}}$ which converges.

Comment: What you said is wrong, you can't sum equivalent like that. What I did it just giving an equivalent of the general term, and since the series of $\frac{1}{n^\frac{5}{2}}$ converges then it's also the case for your series (since this is a series with positive terms).